# Unable to start eclipse "java.lang.LinkageError"

Tags: eclipse

I have trouble strating my Eclipse Kepler.
The log file shows a "Could not run processor error" :*

```
!SESSION 2015-07-11 17:27:36.405 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product -pluginCustomization D:\NVPACK\eclipse\nvpref.ini
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product -pluginCustomization D:\NVPACK\eclipse\nvpref.ini

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 2 0 2015-07-11 17:27:41.577
!MESSAGE Could not run processor
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/ContextFunction"
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelAssembler.runProcessor(ModelAssembler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelAssembler.processModel(ModelAssembler.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/ContextFunction"
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.getHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.commands.CommandPersistence.readCommandsFromRegistry(CommandPersistence.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.commands.CommandPersistence.reRead(CommandPersistence.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.CommandToModelProcessor.process(CommandToModelProcessor.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    ... 26 more
```

This is quite annoying since I need to finish an important piece of work.
I searched the internet but it doesn't seem there is a lot about this issue.

Any ideas ?
thank you for your help

Comment: I think you have a corrupt Eclipse. Download latest one from the official site.

Comment: I downloaded an official Eclipse.. which was working until now.. I don't know what could have happen

Comment: I mean download it again. 99% this is a corrupt Eclipse installation.

Comment: ok, i will try reinstallation. thank you for your help

Answer (score 9):

Reinstall would certainly work, but it seems like a large hatchet to me.

What I found working for me is finding one of those `org.eclipse.e4.core*` packages. Most likely they will be in the `plugins` directory. Then just delete them one by one and re-try loading Eclipse. Once Eclipse is up you can reinstall the specific plugin if needed. But at least you will preserve all the projects and other settings.

Answer (score 7):

if you have Eclipse installed, go to : "home directory".p2\pool\plugins
if it's not installed, go to : plugins directory

in my case, I had three version of org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts :
[image]

the three of these packages were referenced on artifacts.xml, two of them were also referenced on feature.xml for packages org.eclipse.e4.rcp(two different versions).

I simply removed the oldest jars and kept the newest org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts_1.8.100
Eclipse is back to life =D

P.S. : Bonus! Eclipse is running suddenly faster

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

Thanks to ilya1725 i found /plugins/org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts_1.3.100.v20140407-1019 was causing this. After its removal eclipse is starting again without need of a reinstallation.

Comment: Don't forget to Accept ilya1725's answer.

Comment: After removing above package, its working for me, also ilya1725 comment good